# Lex and Yacc for Finite Automata

Tags: finite-automata

I want to develop a tool to construct the transition graph of any finite automata given its transition table, start state and final state using **Lex and Yacc**. Tool should also provide a facility to check whether a string is accepted by the automata or not.

Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a helpful [introduction](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/courses/cs471/lec/cs471-03-lex.pdf). Implementation of a DFA in lex, with source code and quite detailed illustrations.

Comment: DFA= Deterministic Finite Automata?